# Ajax Delete request & response in Node / Express - after method called how can I redirect with a GET method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am new to AJAX and Node and wasn't sure how to handle this:
I have a DELETE ajax call which after removing the row from the db I would like to redirect back to the same route, but with a GET method. I believe I could redirect the page from the front-end script as well, I am not sure which is the correct strategy. Any help is appreciated!

**front-end js making ajax call script.js**

```
  $('.deleteRepository').on('click', function(event) {    
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var username = $(this).attr('username');
    var repoName = $(this).attr('repoName');
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("delete", "/user/"+username+'/'+repoName);
    oReq.send();
  });
```

**myRoute.js**

```
router.route('/:username/:repository')
    .delete(function(req, res) {
      console.log('\n\nDelete method called\n\n');
      let username = req.params.username;
      let repoName = req.params.repository;

      deleteRepositoryFromUser(req, res)
        .then(function() {
          console.log('deleted, now redirect');
          //I want to redirect to this page using GET, but logs DELETE
          //I also want to redirect to /user/TonyStark/Favorites
          res.redirect(200, '/user/'+username+'/Favorites'); 
        })
```

**console**

```
GET /user/TonyStark/delMe 200 114.702 ms - 4075
...    

Delete method called


deleteRepositoryFromUser()
repoName: delMe
username: TonyStark
deleted, now redirect
DELETE /user/TonyStark/delMe 200 4.568 ms - 44 //how can I make GET?
//why is it not going to /user/TonyStark/Favorites?
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong `res.redirect(200, '/user/'+username+'/Favorites');`. You can't redirect with code 200. You have to redirect either with 301 or 302. Check here for reference on the http codes: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Thanks Svabael. However, when I tried that it keeps recursively submitting the request in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually set the HTTP method to GET before redirecting. 
In **myRoute.js**:

```
router.route('/:username/:repository')
.delete(function(req, res) {
  console.log('\n\nDelete method called\n\n');
  let username = req.params.username;
  let repoName = req.params.repository;

  deleteRepositoryFromUser(req, res)
    .then(function() {
      console.log('deleted, now redirect');

      //Explicitly set the HTTP method to GET
      req.method = "GET"

      res.redirect(200, '/user/'+username+'/Favorites'); 
    })
```